# JerseyTest fails because HttpServletRequest is null

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I´m using JerseyTest with a resource that uses a validateSession method before, when the resource don´t use validateSession it works fine, but extending the class with validateSession throw a 500 error in the test. I think is because in the test the HttpServletRequest is null. I try to first make a login before the test in the same method test, but fail. Any help. This is the simple resource:

```
@Path("/test")
public class Prueba extends BaseLoginWebService {

final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Prueba.class);

@GET
public String saludo() {
    return "it works";
  }
}
```

The resource in order to return the String, use BaseLoginWebService with validateSession method, previously it use a LoginWebService:

```
public class BaseLoginWebService {

@Context
HttpServletRequest request;

final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Prueba.class);

@PostConstruct
public void init() throws Exception {
    validateSession();
}

private void validateSession() throws Exception {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    String token = null;
    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
        if ((cookie.getValue().equals(session.getAttribute("token")))) {
            token = (String) session.getAttribute("token");
            break;
        }
    }
    if (token == null) {
        throw new Exception("no session");
    }
}
}
```

LoginWebService:

```
@Path("/login")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class LoginWebService {

@Context
HttpServletRequest request;

@POST
public Response login(LoginEntity loginEntity) {
    if (loginEntity != null) {
        if (loginEntity.getUser().equals("root") && loginEntity.getPassword().equals("root")) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setMaxInactiveInterval(5);
            Random random = new Random();
            int token = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
            session.setAttribute("token", String.valueOf(token));
            return Response.noContent().cookie(new NewCookie("token", String.valueOf(token))).build();
        } else {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }
    } else {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.CONFLICT).build();
    } 
}
}
```

The resource works fine, but in testing doesn't:

```
public class PruebaTest extends JerseyTest {

@Override
public Application configure() {
    enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);
    enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
    return new ResourceConfig(Prueba.class);
}

@Override
protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() throws TestContainerException {
    return new ExternalTestContainerFactory();
}

@Override
protected URI getBaseUri() {
    URI uri = UriBuilder.fromPath("http://localhost:9090/messenger_webapp/rest").build();
    return uri;
}

@Test
public void saludoTest() {
    System.out.println("saludoTest");
    String output = target("/test").request().get(String.class);
    assertEquals("Should return it works", "it works", output);
}
}
```

The error:

```
javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Request failed.

at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:1020)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:816) 
  ..... and more .....
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't provided any details about how your application is deployed, HttpServletResponse is available for injection only when the application is deployed in servlet containers (Tomcat, for example). It might be your problem.

I had similar problem with GrizzlyHttpServer. Cause of my issue was, Grizzly provides similar abstractions to those offered by the Servlet specification: HttpHandler (Servlet), Request (HttpServletRequest), Response (HttpServletResponse).

So I had to use: `import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request;`
instead of: `import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;`

Answer (score 1):

Please check which testcontainer you're using. According to the docs at https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/test-framework.html

> In-Memory container is not a real container. It starts Jersey
>   application and directly calls internal APIs to handle request created
>   by client provided by test framework. There is no network
>   communication involved. This containers does not support servlet and
>   other container dependent features, but it is a perfect choice for
>   simple unit tests.

So if you're using the in memory container and try to use servlet features it won't work. In this case try using the grizzly provider or something else which is close to your final deploy target